# How important are $R^2$ values with few plots

Tags: regression, sample-size, r-squared

I have multiple variables I resampled (once in 1977 and again in 2015). Each variable had 6 samples collected in each sampling period. I'm trying to 'correct' another set of 1977 samples not resampled in 2015 to match 2015 data (not sampled in 1977) by  regressing my 6 resampled samples for each variable. But I only have 6 samples, so about half of my variables return a very low (<0.1) or negative $R^2$ value. This tells me the model is no good ... but is that true? Since I have no option of adding more samples, what should my next move be? Ignore the $R^2$ and use the regression anyway (most of them look ok graphically anyway) or am I up a creek without enough paddles (samples)?

Comment: I'll note that I've examined R's diagnostic plots for regression and seen some issues (i.e., linearity, heteroscedasticity). But again, with only 6 plots, it seems like these plots were difficult to interpret.

Comment: To press the analogy, it sounds like this analysis is only as good as the liquid in the creek... .

Comment: So I can make the R2 better (and positive) by adding an exponential term to the model. But this curve looks wayy worse than the linear line does graphically. So do I go with what looks more sensible graphically, or just blindly believe the R2?...or is this just too few data points to use?

Comment: @theforestecologist - If I am fitting models I use AICc instead of R2 because it accounts for sample size and parameter count as well as error.  Consider this [link](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~shu3/Presentation/AIC.pdf)